# How can I reset iOS 9 Universal Linking settings?

Tags: ios, ios9, ios-universal-links

While testing universal links on my iOS 9 app, I accidentally tapped "mywebsite.com >" (top right corner). This made the app navigate to the website again. Now I can't seem to make universal linking work again. Seems like iOS has remembered my preference that I would like to see links opened in Safari as opposed to my app.

Has anyone run into this? Is there a way to reset this?

Comment: I'm having this problem with Facebook links.  Somebody sends me a link via Messenger, and the link opens in Safari instead of Facebook app. I *one time* dismissed the "Open in Facebook App" button, and now there's no way to restore that setting.  None of the suggestions here work for me.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can long-press on a universal link and it will give you an action sheet with an "Open in 'AppName'" option. Once you select that option it will default to opening the links in your app again.

Comment: Thanks for this.  For the record, this is horrendous UX IMHO

Comment: This won't work in all cases. For example, clicking Tweetbot's Tweet Detail timestamp takes you to a tweet, but does not respond to long presses. hitrain's solution seems more consistent.

Comment: It doesn't work neither in Message for example. To make this work if your link is in an app already using the long touch, copy the link and paste it in Note App for example. After that, if you long touch, this will work as expected (even if "as expected" is just a very bad way to do this !!! :)

Answer (score 10):

You need pull down in opened page in safari from email, etc to see button "Open" (this button is system in safari). If tap "open" after

> I accidentally tapped "mywebsite.com >"

universal link will work again under the old scheme.The result of this action preserves.

[example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vg5pyn44yibojqk/%D0%A1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%202015-09-23%20%D0%B2%2013.23.52.png?dl=0)

Comment: I dont see the small "open" banner either if I pull down :(

Answer (score 6):

@dan is right, long-pressing the hyperlink will give you the option to open with your app again through universal link.

If you have an Apple Smart Banner in place, you can also click on its 'Open' hyperlink to active universal links on your app again.

Comment: This may work without Apple Smart Banner code -- at least it did for me

Answer (score 3):

For a Branch.io deep link the long tap (at least in GMail) does not work and also you can't pull down from safari, it brings you to the App Store immediately.

Instead, copy the link to Notes and then do the long press.

More info here: https://blog.branch.io/3-steps-to-troubleshoot-ios-9-and-ios-10-universal-links/